# Optimize Scanner performance for large files

Tags: java, performance, optimization, split, buffer

I wrote a program in Java using a `Scanner` to get two elements separated by a space from each line to put it in an object stocked in an `ArrayList`. It works perfectly, but when it comes to inputs with 10000's of lines, it becomes very long. I read a few topics and websites (such as [this](http://www.cpe.ku.ac.th/~jim/java-io.html)) telling `BufferedReader` would be a lot efficient than `Scanner` but I did not see any improvement while trying.

Here are the lines I use so far to parse each line of my input:

```
  String charsetName = "UTF-8";
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in), charsetName);
```

Then I have a loop running during the number of lines calling:

```
 String[] mid = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
```

So I tried to replace the `Scanner` by:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String[] base = reader.readLine().split(" ");
```

It did not change anything (8 seconds for 12000 lines in both case)

Am I going in the right direction to get the program work a lot faster? Or does the problem come from using a loop to go through each line?

Comment: can you give me an example of a line?

Comment: So you want to put the 2-dimensional array from each line in the ArrayList?

Comment: I noticed that whatever I put inside my loop, as soon as there is " String[] val = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");", then it will take 8 seconds to read the 12000 lines, anything else works in less than 1 second.

Comment: See my code below in my answer that uses String split. Does that make a difference for you?

Comment: quite misread your question at first. i thought you were reading a really huge file, so 8 secs may be realistic. showing an example line would be useful indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code to read through a file of **280,000 lines** (consisting of two words per line separated by a space) and split them on a space. **It took 0.105 seconds**. So I would like to know more about the line you are parsing and what you are doing with it. Paste more code please.

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Date start = new Date();

    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("aa.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = b.readLine())!=null) {
      String[] splat = line.split(" ");
    }
    b.close();

    Date end = new Date();
    System.out.println("Took " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000.0 + " seconds");
  }
```

I modified the code above to add each splat array to an array list (not sure why you want to do this, but I am guessing this is what you are trying to do, from your OP). The code slowed down to 0.244 seconds. Still way less than a second. More info please.

**Supplement - FULL CODE** (compile with `javac Julien.java`). *Remember to replace aa.txt with your file name.*

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Julien {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Date start = new Date();
//    List arrl = new ArrayList();
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("aa.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = b.readLine())!=null) {
      String[] splat = line.split(" ");
//      arrl.add(splat);
    }
    b.close();
    Date end = new Date();
    System.out.println("Took " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000.0 + " seconds");
  }
}
```

Comment: So far I'm doing some very simple tests in order to find where the latency comes from : 

         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
         int a = 12000; // number of lines in my input, i'll specify it anyway
                
                for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
                {       
                  String[] cut = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
                }
                 scanner.close();

With this it takes 8 seconds for 12000 lines, I tried your code xagyg and it never finished compiling.

Comment: @Julien "I tried your code xagyg and it never finished compiling." Well, you need to **put it in a class** and you need to **import java.io.*; import java.util.*;** at the top. I can post the whole class if you like. **You also need to replace aa.txt with your file name OR create aa.txt in your local file system.** Let me know what issues you have. It compiles with a simple javac YourClassName.

Comment: Was 0.105 seconds the first time you ran it after a reboot, or a subsequent run. Disk caching on such a small amount of data could eliminate all disk access.

Comment: @xagyg your code works perfectly while using an external output, but do you know how should I modify "while ((line = b.readLine())!=null) {" to make it work with the system input ? It never ends when I configure the Buffer to read the input. Thanks again !

Comment: Did you try this ... `BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` Also, how are you using standard input (piping or catting a file to your program, or manual entry)?

Comment: Yeah that's the line I'm using, and the input entry is manual.

Comment: Ok, so I figured that running the program while buffering from an outside file (just like with your lines) makes it work pretty fast (11 seconds for 50 000 lines to parse, 1s for 12000, which seems acceptable to me), but when it comes to do the exact same thing with the data from the file put into stdin (like the one in your last comment), then it takes 1 min 20s. How could I configure the buffer to have the same results both ways ?

Comment: Regarding your second-to-last comment, if you are using manual entry and want to finish the input you need to use an EOF character (such as CTRL-D) or, alternatively, use a special word such as "quit" (in which case the loop becomes `while ((line = b.readLine())!=null&&!line.equals("quit"))`. If you use an EOF character you don't need to modify the while.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, that is very strange I don't see why "catting" a file to stdin and piping to your program would make it much slower.

Comment: Thanks for the EOF character tip ! About the stdin issue I haven't find anything yet, read about StringTokenizer in java, do you think that could help ?

Comment: When I use stdin in my example program (above) by using `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` and executing by using `java Julien < aa.txt` there is no noticeable difference in execution time. I don't think I can help further unless you post more of your specific code.